# Resharper multiple property generation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

This might be a lazy request, but is there a way to generate multiple class properties at the same time?  Currently, I have a large list of *undefined properties* and I can simply go through the list, one by one, and generate a property - but it would be ideal to highlight them all and generate one for each, example illustration below...

[image]

You can see here that `prop1`, `prop2`...etc have errors since the properties don't yet exist, but you can generate a property with resharper...

[image]

However, this seems to be one-at-a-time, I was wondering if I am missing a setting?

Comment: Nope, sorry, we don't provide this functionality. If you _really_ need this, consider writing a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Resharper for 5+ years and I'm using Resharper 9.1.3 Ultimate and I don't think what you want is possible.

The only way to make ReSharper create multiple properties at once is to have it implement missing properties from an interface. It might be worth creating a feature request!