# Resharper generate auto-properties for code

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a situation like that : 
[image]

is there any way to generate all of those properties at once rather then clicking on each one ?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32008094/5311735. One of the members of Resharper team says in comments that they do not support this.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst strictly an answer to what you asked, as R# can't do what you want, I find NimbleText (http://nimbletext.com/) to be extremely useful for this sort of thing.

You paste your C# into the top panel, add a template to the second panel, using things like $1, $2, etc for the data fields, and the resultant text appears in the third panel.

One of the most useful tools I've ever found, and free too!

Comment: Thank you that's an extremly useful tool